# Moddel split in half

Tags: modeling, rigging

Im new to blender and curently following a youtube tutorial for making my first 3d character. It was going realy good until i noticed that somewhere in between the rigging and the weight painting my character split in half. I have tryed useing alt+m and also tryed to clean it up via mesh, but i cant get the two halfs back to getter. When moddeling I used the mirror modifier.

I realy hope someone can help me.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: have you applied the mirror? You've tried merge by distance, have you played a bit with the parameters in the operator box (bottom left) to make sure the vertices would merge?

Comment: Thanks for the help, turnes out im realy blond and need to not be scared to try stuff out. i needed to play with the parameters more

Comment: could you please show a screenshot or share at least a part of your object?  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sorry after my reply i took another look and realiced that i did need to play woth the parameters more

Comment: oh ok so you fixed it?

Comment: Yes thanks to your sugestions :)

Comment: Did you have clipping on?